# One step beyond cubic spline interpolation, a fourth-order problem?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, spline

I am trying to fit a polynomial through three points, where I also know the derivatives at the two endpoints.  I don't need a truly general solution.  My specific problem is constrained as follows:

```
f(0) = 1; f'(0) = 0
f(w) = 1/2, where 0 < w < 1/2; f'(w) is unconstrained
f(1) = 0; f'(1) = 0
```

I believe this means I have five degrees of freedom, rather than the usual four DOF of the cubic spline interpolation problem.  Therefore I'm expecting to fit a quartic polynomial through my points.

I know the Taylor series approach to polynomial interpolation, where you have a point and the nth derivatives at that point.  I also know the Vandermonde matrix inversion approach to polynomial interpolation, where you know n points, and the derivatives are not constrained.

I don't know of any polynomial interpolation approach which makes use of a mix of point and derivative information, other than the cubic spline interpolation.  Is there a method which handles my specific problem?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I have a few questions. First, is $w$ a given parameter, or do you just need to have at lest one point in the $(0,1/2)$ interval where $f(w)=1/2$? Secondly, if $w$ is given, why don't you explicitly write out the polynomial, plug in the constraints, and find the coefficients. If $w$ is not given, then you need to find the critical points in the $(0,1/2)$ interval, and compute the value of the function at those points, and also compute $f(1/2)$.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for your reply.  The value of w is known exactly, not just constrained to the interval (0,1/2).  I'm working through the constraints problem right now.  It's messy, because it involves five variables, and a mix of values and derivatives.  I was hoping for a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$
Then $$f'(x)=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d$$
Your conditions are $$f(0)=e=1\\f'(0)=d=0\\f(1)=a+b+c+1=0\\f'(1)=4a+3b+2c=0\\f(w)=aw^4+bw^3+cw^2+1=1/2$$
The last three lines form a system of three linear equations with three unknowns. You can use Cramer's rule to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I got that far about 30 minutes after I posted my question.  So, we agree on the method.  I was hoping for something less cumbersome and more general.  I'm checking the results of solving the system of equations by calculating some representative points.  It's looking wrong.  I must have a flipped minus sign somewhere.  Sigh.